# Rails: Find biggest number out of val.size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, size

```
user = SkillUser.find_all_by_skill_id(skill_id)
user.size
```

gives me: 1 2 2 1 3 1 3 1 3 2 1 1 3

How can I get the biggest value (in this case 3) out of this row of numbers?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `maximum` scope on your ActiveRelation:

```
SkillUser.maximum(:rating)
```

If you want the maximum of an attribute called `rating`.

---

If you want to count the number of users per skill id, try:

```
SkillUser.count(:group => :skill_id).max_by { |skill_id,count| count }
```

This gives you both the skill_id and the number of users for the skill with most users.

For a more efficient way (by doing the whole calculation in SQL), try:

```
SkillUser.limit(1).reverse_order.count(:group => :skill_id, :order => :count)
# Giving the SQL:
# => SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, "skill_users"."skill_id" AS skill_id
#    FROM "skill_users" GROUP BY "skill_users"."skill_id"
#    ORDER BY "skill_users"."count" DESC LIMIT 1
```

Be aware that `count` must be called last because it doesn't return an ActiveRelation for you to further scope the query.

Comment: sorry no.. this I already have tried..undefined method `max' for 1:Fixnum

Comment: what attribute do you want to get the maximum value of?

Comment: Gives: undefined method `size' for #<SkillUser id: 115, skill_id: 89, user_id: 9, rating: "4">

Comment: I am not looking for an attribute.. just the max number of users per skill_id

Comment: find_all_by_skill_id(skill_id)
in a join table

Comment: you mean you count # of users for skill id = 1, then # for skill id = 2, ..., and you want the maximum count?

Comment: that is it..
user.size or count gives then this row of numers 1425..and I need the biggest number out of it..Thanks so far

Comment: SkillUser.count(:group => :skill_id).max_by { |skill_id,count| count } => [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3] [1, 3]

Comment: well, the result of that is just `[1,3]`, which indicates that there are 3 users with `skill_id` of 1. And no other `skill_id` has more than 3.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ActiveRecord::Calculations
http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html
for performance reasons

```
1.9.3-194 (main):0 > User.maximum(:id)
   (1.6ms)  SELECT MAX("users"."id") AS max_id FROM "users" 
=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Fastest way to find a single maximum value in an unsorted list of
   integer is to scan the list from left to right and memorize the
   largest value so far.
2. If you sort the list first, you get the
   additional benefit of easily finding the 2nd, 3rd etc. largest
   values easily as well.
3. If you take one of the "maximum" methods hidden in ruby ... you should check what the implementors are doing to pick the max and compare it to 1. and 2. above :-)

Explanations:

to 1. Doing it this way, you just have to pick each value in the list exactly once and compare it once to the maximum so-far.

to 2. Sorting costs O(n*log n) ops in the average if you got a list with n entries. Obviously this is more than the O(n) in solution 1., but you get a bit more

to 3. Well.. I prefer knowing what happens, but your preferences might vary